# Bounce velocity calculation, collision with ground

Tags: canvas, collision-detection, physics, game-physics, gravity

On a canvas, I have a ball falling to earth under gravity

```
vy += gravity
ball.y += vy
```

I want the ball to bounce so I have implemented an approximate solution to detect if the ball has gone past the boundary of the ground, and if so, to reset it's position to the ground, and to flip it's velocity in the negative direction.

```
if (ball.y + ball.radius > bottom) {
ball.y = bottom - ball.radius;
vy *= -1;
```

However, I want this to be 100% accurate. To do this ball.y will need to be positioned slightly above the ground, and it's velocity will be slightly less than -vy because gravity will already have started to slow it. How can I calculate these more accurate values?

The distance below the ground will be `ball.y + ball.radius - bottom`. So there must be a formula which will convert this into a distance above the ground which I think is `ball.y = (2 * bottom) - ball.y - 2*ball.radius;`

Here's where I'm getting stuck. Am I right so far? I now need to calculate the new velocity. I'm sure it's possible but I just can't get my head around it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete demo that demonstrates gravity and bounce physics:

[**Bouncing Ball (jsfiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/r2rS6/)

---

The code is self explicative but the main portion that do the simulation is the update function which contains the code below:

```
// calculate new position
ball.x += ball.vx;
ball.y += ball.vy;

// bounce Y (don't bounce on top)
if (ball.y >= bottom - ball.radius) {
    ball.y = bottom - ball.radius; // (!) GROUND LIMIT
    ball.vy = -(ball.vy * ball.elasticity);
}

// bounce X
if ((ball.x >= right - ball.radius) || (ball.x <= left + ball.radius)) {

    ball.x = (ball.x < (left + ball.radius) ? (left + ball.radius) : (right - ball.radius));
    ball.vx = -(ball.vx * ball.elasticity);
}

// compute gravity
ball.vy += gravity;

// compute frictions
ball.vx *= airDrag;
ball.vy *= airDrag;
if (ball.y >= (bottom - ball.radius)) {
    ball.vx *= groundFriction;
}
```

The code above adds three different physics variables that creates a more realistic simulation:

- `ball.elasticity`: coefficient of restitution;
- `airDrag`:  drag coefficient;
- `groundFriction`: friction applied on movement over the ground.

All variables above are represented by values from 0 to 1. Values closest to 1 means more elasticity, less air drag and less friction. Values closest to 0 means less elasticity, more air drag and more friction.

---

### Advanced Physics Simulation - if you are encouraged and have a basic grasp of physics and mathematics:

If you want an even more realistic simulation you could update the `airDrag` dynamically by using the [drag equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation).

Another improvement is to calculate velocity with more accurate algorithms based on numerical integration. Here is a nice example comparing the most used integration methods in game development: http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/aug/28/integration-by-example-euler-vs-verlet-vs-runge-kutta/#

You can also make use of a physics engine like [box2d-web](https://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/) if you need more complicated simulations.

Answer (score 1):

**There are several factors that affect a falling object as it hits the ground**

You can adjust for the loss of energy during a bounce by adding a "restitution" factor.

Essentially, restitution represents the bounciness of the ball and ranges from 0-1.

Restitution==0 means the ball doesn't bounce at all--it stops on the ground like a bowling ball.

Restitution==1 means the ball doesn't lose any velocity at all during a bounce.

To implement restitution, you just multiply velocity by restitution:

```
vy *= restitutionFactor;
```

If your ball is dropping at an angle, you might also consider implementing "friction" which is an adjustment to directional velocity during a bounce.

Friction represents the loss of directional velocity when your rough ball "rubs" on the floor.

Friction is represented by values from 0 to 1 and is implemented like restitution:

```
vx *= frictionFactor;
```

**A step-by-step illustration**

Assume on Frame#1 the ball has not bounced and is above the ground.

Assume on Frame#2 the ball has bounced and is back in the air.

You have these calculations to make to get Frame#2 ball position.

(1) Save the ball's initial position and initial velocity (we'll need them later):

```
startingY = ball.y;
startingVelocity = vy;
```

(2) The ball uses part of the Frame-time to drop to the ground:

```
ball.y = bottom;
```

(3) The ball hits the ground and reverses velocity:

```
vy* = -1;
```

(4) The new upward velocity is adjusted by restitution and friction:

```
vy *= restitution;
vx *= friction;     // if moving at an angle
```

(5) The ball used part of this frame-time moving downward, so the ball gets less than a full frame-time worth of upward velocity:

```
downtime = ( bottom - startingY ) / startingVelocity;
uptime = (1 - downtime);
```

(6) The ball bounces upward for the appropriate fraction of a frame and at the new velocity:

```
ball.y += vy * uptime;
```

There's another factor you can introduce--ball "smush".

Smush means the ball becomes temporarily flat on its bottom when hitting the ground.

During smush, velocity is suspended. So smush is a delay-time.

Smush varies with the resilience of your ball...more resilience == more smush delay.

You adjust for smush by reducing the "uptime" that the ball can use to move upward.

Revisiting step#5:

```
uptime = (1 - downtime - smushtime);
```

These are the standard adjustments to a moving ball...enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You already used an acceleration: gravity.

Why not use another acceleration: bounce.

The only you need is to make "bounce" exponential so it cannot penetrate the ground level because you apply that acceleration only after ball is **"close enough to ground"**  not below or exact location.

Gravity: constant everywhere.
Bounce: only exists after some distance to ground(Because ball has a radius and there will be some buffer distance to let the ball accelerate under "bounce")

Then let this acceleration do its job rather than fiddling with many if statements and special calculations. The fact is in reality its an acceleration because of Pauli's Exclusion Principle + ElectroMagnetism.

```
vy += gravity
if(closeEnough)
{
    bounce=bConstant/pow(distance,3.0f)
    vy-=bounce      //this bounce will be calculated as F=bConstant/pow(distance,3.0f)
                    // bConstant is a small number that you try and choose
                    //That power does not have to be 3. You can try different values.
}
ball.y += vy
```

Exponential exclusion force makes it harder and harder for the ball to approach for every pixel closer to ground then you see a natural bouncing movement there.

You cant be %100 accurate, even in real world you cannot be. Decrease your timestep to a value as low as you can. Dont just add acceleration to velocity directly. In your example, you have timestep of 1 (directly adding acceleration to velocity).

Lets have smaller timestep(such as 0.1f) to have a more stable and more accurate movement:

```
timeStep = 0.1f;
vy += gravity * timeStep;
if(closeEnough)
{
    bounce=bConstant/pow(distance,3.0f)
    vy-=bounce * timeStep     
            //this bounce will be calculated as F=bConstant/pow(distance,3.0f)
            // bConstant is a small number that you try and choose
           //That power does not have to be 3. You can try different values.
}
ball.y += vy * timeStep
```

Also using a timestep makes it possible to use correct acceleration and displacement according to FPS of your game. (timestep = 1/ FPS)

There are mainly three types of integration for displacement. Euler's Integration, Verlet Integration and Runge-Kutta Integration. What you are using is very simple version of Euler's. Fastest but unstable/not accurate.

You can google Verlet and Runge-Kutta when you use thousands of balls bouncing from each other.